# Decoupling the Dal Repository using the Factory pattern

Tags: architecture, repository, factory-pattern, decoupling

I'm trying to decouple the Bll from the Dal using some interfaces and a Factory patter.
Data.Contracts containing the interfaces will be referenced on my Bll.

This is a small test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IDataRepositoryFactory _DataRepositoryFactory;
        IUserRepository userRepository = _DataRepositoryFactory.GetDataRepository<IUserRepository>();
     }
}


public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class, new() { }
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository 
{
    public UserRepository() { }
}

public class DataRepositoryFactory : IDataRepositoryFactory
{
    public T GetDataRepository<T>() where T : IDataRepository, new()
    {
        return ObjectBase.Container.GetExportedValue<T>();
    }
}

public class User 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ObjectBase
{
    public ObjectBase() { }

    public static CompositionContainer Container { get; set; }

}

public interface IDataRepository { }

public interface IDataRepository<T> : IDataRepository where T : class, new() { }

public interface IUserRepository : IDataRepository { }

public interface IDataRepositoryFactory
{
    T GetDataRepository<T>() where T : IDataRepository, new();
}
```

An finally I got my error:

'Data.Contracts.IUserRepository' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order 
to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Data.Contracts.IDataRepositoryFactory.GetDataRepository()'

**My question is:
Which is the correct implementation to Decouple the code on the Business layer using the factory pattern?
I can not use the concrete implementation UserRepository since it inherits from classes that I do not want in the BLL.**

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code perspective you should just disable "new" constraint on factory interface:

```
public interface IDataRepositoryFactory
{
    T GetDataRepository<T>() where T : IDataRepository; //, new();
}

public class DataRepositoryFactory : IDataRepositoryFactory
{
    public T GetDataRepository<T>() where T : IDataRepository//, new()
    {
        return ObjectBase.Container.GetExportedValue<T>();
    }
}
```

---

From the design point of view repositories look a bit complicated:

[image]

For me IDataRepository (non-generic) and RepositoryBase seem redundant, but that depends of the exact case (probably you didn't provide enough details). I'd use `IDataRepository<T>  ->  IUserRepository:IDataRepository<User> -> UserRepository` inheritance chain.

Also it's not clear what types belong to BLL.

For example, this breakdown looks all right to me:

- BLL:

  - `User`
  - `IUserRepository:IDataRepository<User>`
- DAL/Infrastructure:

  - `IDataRepositoryFactory`
  - `IDataRepositoryFactory:IDataRepositoryFactory`
  - `IDataRepository<T>`
  - `UserRepository`

In general I'd suggest to simplify code structure and start with the simplest possible way, then adding new interfaces/classes when you really need them.

Comment: Thanks, I have found in my implementation one Constraint that wasn't working, I have rebuilt a small console application, with a simpler model and DI and solved.